# Android: Keyboard not displaying the edit area on Device

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a keyboard related problem in my android app. The edit view is not showing with keyboard on device.

The emulator is setup on Android3.3 and it shows the keyboard as follows:

[image]

The entered text "new" is visible on top of the keyboard. This keyboard occupies half of the screen.

I have the same android version on device as well. On device this keyboard is shown but what ever I entered from keyboard doesn't appears on top of keyboard. But whatever I type is actually captured and going back from keyboard will show the text on `edittext`.

I also tested this on a device with Android2.2 and it also shows the keyboard on full screen with `editbox` with it. That is also fine. The problem is on Android3.3 Device keyboard.

My EditText code is:

> ```
>   edittext = new EditText(this);
>     edittext.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
>     edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
>         public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
>             if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
>                     event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
>                     event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {                     
>                 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
>                 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
>                 return true;    
>             }
>             return false;
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: @Vodemki i have post the code

Comment: One of the device is HTC Android2.2 and it is working good. The device that is creating problem is Dell Streak 5

Comment: Could you post some screens of the keyboard running Android 2.2?

Comment: The keyboard on Android2.2 is like the same on this link: http://sidemission.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/getting-the-htc-keyboard-work-with-android-donut-update/ ... without a Done button

Comment: @user370305 yes android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" is already set in the manifest for an activity

Comment: also "adjustResize" has same effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this config in AndroidManifest.xml with an Android 3.0+ app

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ... />
```